# Change Parameter value based on loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

How can I loop through html tables based off if they are visibile or not and assign different parameters values for each loop. Not sure if this is the correct way to approach this but would like some advice and some sample code of how to accomplish the following if possible.

Table example

```
Four of these tables so for the second table I have the id="txtLName1"
    <table id="tblEvent1" class="tblAttendee">
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="txtLName" runat="server" type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="txtFName" runat="server" type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" Width="65%">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age:</td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAge" runat="server" Width="65%">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comments:</td>
                    <td><textarea id="txtComments" runat="server" type="text"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

Table1 - visible = true
Table2 - visible = true
Table3 - visible = true
Table4 - visible = false

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Loop through tables where visible = true
//first loop
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Request.Form["(Table1.LastName"]);
insert new record to database
//second loop
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Request.Form["Table2.LastName"]);
insert new record to database using same storedprocedure call
//third loop
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Request.Form["Table3.LastName"]);
insert new record to database using same storedprocedure call
No 4th loop because Table is not visible.
```

The database table in the end should have something like this in it using the same stored procedure but looping so it would be called multiple times to insert 3 records in this case

```
(LastName)Smith (firstName)Bob (gender)Male (age)13 (linkid)1
(LastName)Smith (firstName)Timmy (gender)Male (age)7 (linkid)1
(LastName)Smith (firstName)Jenny (gender)Female (age)9 (linkid)1
```

Comment: are you using web forms or mvc? what the code on the page looks like? how the tables are populated?

Comment: I added an example of the table TomT this is webforms asp.net C# and the sql table will populate based on the fields listed. Maybe i did not ask the question clearly enough but I am trying to depending on how many tables are visible on my webpage loop through insert the first table into the database then the loop would insert the second table as a new record and so on

Answer (score 0):

changed the sql stored procedure to accept all parameters but only insert into the table if they are not null